# ANTLR to get symbolicNames when walking the parser tree

Tags: go, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm following https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2017/parsing-with-antlr4-and-go/, and
I'm looking at https://github.com/bramp/goadvent-antlr/blob/master/example2.go, which has no output. Now,

I want to use the [`EnterEveryRule`](https://github.com/bramp/goadvent-antlr/blob/c08e55aa6f4a6ba745bbe3e9abbeeeaa2a16e225/parser/calc_base_listener.go#L19) to output each symbol encountered, with their symbolicNames. How can I do that?

I.e., how to somehow access to the [`symbolicNames`](https://github.com/bramp/goadvent-antlr/blob/c08e55aa6f4a6ba745bbe3e9abbeeeaa2a16e225/parser/calc_parser.go#L36-L37) slice at any specific stage, to know which SymbolicName I'm dealing with.

Comment: CalcParser is [subclassed from Parser](https://github.com/bramp/goadvent-antlr/blob/c08e55aa6f4a6ba745bbe3e9abbeeeaa2a16e225/parser/calc_parser.go#L52), which is [subclassed from Recognizer](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/c71fa7eae68e55f9dac82242792be0a43d3c54ec/runtime/Go/antlr/parser.go#L36), which contains [GetSymbolicNames()](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/c71fa7eae68e55f9dac82242792be0a43d3c54ec/runtime/Go/antlr/recognizer.go#L16). Call `p.GetSymbolicNames()` where p is a CalcParser struct.

Comment: Thanks @kaby76. I believe that I still need to use `antlr.ParseTreeWalkerDefault.Walk`, but from within there, suppose I've somehow used `GetSymbolicNames()` to get the slice `..."OPP", "CLP", "MUL", "DIV", "ADD", "SUB", "NUMBER", "WHITESPACE"`, how would I know at a specific stage, which SymbolicName I'm dealing with? That's the question I want to solve. Thx!

Comment: The ParserRuleContext of a parse tree can be either internal nodes or leaf nodes. A node should be casted to TerminalNode (probably something like `t, ok := ctx.(TerminalNode)`). With a pointer to TerminalNode, you can get the token type (`t.GetSymbol().GetTokenType()`), which is an integer that you use on the array returned by GetSymbolicNames().

Comment: Maybe something like this: `func (l *calcListener) EnterEveryRule(ctx antlr.ParserRuleContext) { t, ok := ctx.(antlr.TerminalNode); if ok { x := t.GetSymbol().GetTokenType(); y := l.parser.GetSymbolicNames(); fmt.Println(y[x]); } }` minus the correct Go formatting, semi-colons removed, etc., and adding `parser antlr.Parser` in calcListener struct.

Comment: Wow, I'd never be able to come up solution like this myself. Would you answer the question instead then @kaby76, please? I've prepared everything for you at https://play.golang.org/p/dXFgk4FPGfQ. So far it seems that for the `t, ok := `, `ok` will always be false.

Comment: I couldn't get that Go "play" server working--timeout. Using VSCode (the "Go" extension is pretty good), "ok" is false because ExitEveryRule() is only called for internal nodes! Geezus H Kryste guys. Try this: `func (l *calcListener) ExitEveryRule(ctx antlr.ParserRuleContext) { count := ctx.GetChildCount(); if count == 1 { ch := ctx.GetChild(0); q := ch.(antlr.Tree); t, ok := q.(antlr.TerminalNode); if ok { s := t.GetSymbol(); x := s.GetTokenType(); y := l.parser.GetSymbolicNames(); fmt.Println(y[x]); } } }`

Comment: (I generally don't add "answers" because I seem to always get downvoted, always corrected. Someday I'll try "answering" again.)

Comment: Thanks @kaby76. OK, I'll answer it for you then.

Answer (score 1):

I'm certainly no expert with Go, but that example contains the following lines:

```
    // Finally parse the expression (by walking the tree)
    antlr.ParseTreeWalkerDefault.Walk(&calcListener{}, p.Start())
```

This is a bit misleading.  The `p.Start()` part of that statement actually does the parsing (calling `p.Start()` should return an ANTLR parse tree.  At that point, you've done the parsing.

`antlr.ParseTreeWalkerDefault.Walk()` is how you walk a parse tree invoking methods on the `listener` that is passed in along with the parse Tree you got from the `p.start()` call.  You may want to store it in a temporary variable before passing it to the walker (maybe inspect it in a debugger to understand it, or, it should have something like a `toStringTree(...)` function that will give you a string representation of the parse tree.)

it appears that `calcListener` just has a reference to a `parser.BaseCalcListener`.  The ANTLR-generated `Base*Listener`s are "do-nothing" listeners that just provide empty implementations of all the methods a listener needs to have implemented.

You'll need to do something with the `calcListener` to "override" the `EnterEveryRule` function, and do something with the `*Context` object passed to it.

Comment: Thanks! About the last step, _"do something with the *Context object"_, that's where I got stuck and don't know how to get from the `*Context` object `antlr.ParserRuleContext` to the Tokens (`NUMBER`, `ADD`, etc) that I'm dealing with in that particular parse tree.

Comment: I’m not a Go programmer, so I’m not familiar with the Go ANTLR target. From the comments it looks like @kaby76 has those details covered though.

Comment: Thanks! Up voting!

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering it for **@kaby76** actually, who had led me to https://play.golang.org/p/R8Sik7sdZaz, so that I am able to move on to
https://play.golang.org/p/uZqfUhHE0mt

Here is the full code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr"

    "github.com/bramp/goadvent-antlr/parser"
)

type calcListener struct {
    *parser.BaseCalcListener
    parser *parser.CalcParser
}

// ExitEveryRule is called when any rule is exited.
func (l *calcListener) ExitEveryRule(ctx antlr.ParserRuleContext) {
    count := ctx.GetChildCount()
    // count == 1, NUMBER
    ch := ctx.GetChild(0)
    if count == 3 {
        // operation
        ch = ctx.GetChild(1)
    }
    q := ch.(antlr.Tree)
    t, ok := q.(antlr.TerminalNode)
    if ok {
        s := t.GetSymbol()
        x := s.GetTokenType()
        y := l.parser.GetSymbolicNames()
        fmt.Println(y[x], ctx.GetText())
    }
}

func main() {
    // Setup the input
    is := antlr.NewInputStream("1 + 2 * 3")

    // Create the Lexer
    lexer := parser.NewCalcLexer(is)
    stream := antlr.NewCommonTokenStream(lexer, antlr.TokenDefaultChannel)

    // Create the Parser
    p := parser.NewCalcParser(stream)

    // Finally parse the expression (by walking the tree)
    listener := calcListener{}
    listener.parser = p
    antlr.ParseTreeWalkerDefault.Walk(&listener, p.Start())
}
```

Execution result:

```
NUMBER 1
NUMBER 2
NUMBER 3
MUL 2*3
ADD 1+2*3
```